# Setting Android AVD Command Line Hardware Profile

Tags: android, scripting, command-line, batch-file, android-virtual-device

When creating a new Android AVD through command line through the following command:

```
android create avd -n <name>
```

You're met with the following output:

```
Do you wish to create a custom hardware profile [no]
```

I've been tasked with created a fully-automated script that will create a new AVD and run some tests (using Robotium).  So far, I've just been using simple batch file commands to achieve this, however, I can't seem to find a way to prevent the above message from appearing and requiring user input.  Is there any way I can either set the hardware profile prior to this message appearing?

Since the default hardware profile is actually preferred in my case, simply hitting 'Enter' when this message appears (in some automated way) would work fine as well, however I am not aware of a way to do this through scripting.

I am fairly new to both aspects of this question, both Android and scripting, so any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

try

```
echo no | android create avd -n <name>
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid "Do you wish to create custom hardware profile"

Type in below **command**:

> echo. | android create avd -f -n Emulator_01 -t 3 -b default/x86
>   --skin WVGA800 | echo.

Emulator will be created under avd manager..!!

Comment: ty! this worked but I had to use echo 'no' both before and after on osx; I got error on echo. [no space] and echo . [space before dot]. I was trying to test out commands from https://github.com/andstatus/andstatus/blob/master/.travis.yml which I found through question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12846469/how-to-create-android-emulator-in-command-line-with-options

Comment: echo. | avdmanager create avd --name myvd1 --package 'system-images;android-22;google_apis;x86' | echo.

Command 'echo.' not found, did you mean: