# how to create android emulator in command line with options?

Tags: android, android-emulator, automation

I want to create emulator in command line with some options, like `hw.mainKeys = false`.
I need it to be an shell script so can run on automation test,however [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html) I could not find a place to set those values.

```
android create avd
```

do not have a place to specify those options.

One alternative is create a 'platform' type avd, however, the shell is a interactive shell that is great for human but hard for script

```
Android 4.1 is a basic Android platform.
Do you wish to create a custom hardware profile [no]yes 

Name of the AVD being run: 
avd.name [<build>]:
```

Are there some tools I can just pass options as parameters, like `--hw.mainKeys false` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create text file config.ini with desired parameters

```
hw.lcd.density=252
sdcard.size=32M
skin.name=NEXUS-ONE
skin.path=platforms/android-10/skins/NEXUS-ONE
hw.cpu.arch=arm
hw.keyboard.lid=no
abi.type=armeabi
hw.keyboard=no
vm.heapSize=24
hw.ramSize=256
image.sysdir.1=platforms/android-10/images/
```

See official documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html)

Comment: how can I use the config.ini later?

Comment: got it. it can be copied to name.avd/ folder. Thanks

Comment: As of August 2016 the "android tool" is no longer supported, as states a note on the documentation page https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/help/android.html. This, on one hand, explains, why I still cannot get it working properly in Travis CI , where I use "android create avd" from a command line, and on the other hand, makes this answer outdated - it looks like we need to seach for some new way to create emulator from a command line...

Comment: @yvolk do you know of any replacement? Or is this still deprecated without proper successor?

Comment: @david.schreiber Since my previous comment I managed to minimize usage of the "android tool"'s command line parameters by providing most of configuration parameters via config.ini file, created by Android Studio. See https://github.com/andstatus/andstatus/blob/master/.travis.yml

Comment: Thanks for coming back @yvolk! I'm now using similar approach with preloading different AVD config files (for my use case) which works very well 

Comment: I have same problem with jenkins CI and jenkins can not create AVD

Answer (score 6):

The non-deprecated command has fewer commandline options, but they are:

```
$ $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/avdmanager --help create 

Usage:
      avdmanager [global options] create [action options]
      Global options:
  -s --silent     : Silent mode, shows errors only.
  -v --verbose    : Verbose mode, shows errors, warnings and all messages.
     --clear-cache: Clear the SDK Manager repository manifest cache.
  -h --help       : Help on a specific command.

Valid actions are composed of a verb and an optional direct object:
- create avd          : Creates a new Android Virtual Device.

Action "create avd":
  Creates a new Android Virtual Device.
Options:
  -a --snapshot: Place a snapshots file in the AVD, to enable persistence.
  -c --sdcard  : Path to a shared SD card image, or size of a new sdcard for
                 the new AVD.
  -g --tag     : The sys-img tag to use for the AVD. The default is to
                 auto-select if the platform has only one tag for its system
                 images.
  -p --path    : Directory where the new AVD will be created.
  -k --package : Package path of the system image for this AVD (e.g.
                 'system-images;android-19;google_apis;x86'). [required]
  -n --name    : Name of the new AVD. [required]
  -f --force   : Forces creation (overwrites an existing AVD)
  -b --abi     : The ABI to use for the AVD. The default is to auto-select the
                 ABI if the platform has only one ABI for its system images.
  -d --device  : The optional device definition to use. Can be a device index
                 or id.
```

Answer (score 5):

From `android --help create avd`:

```
   Usage:
   android [global options] create avd [action options]
   Global options:
  -s --silent     : Silent mode, shows errors only.
  -v --verbose    : Verbose mode, shows errors, warnings and all messages.
     --clear-cache: Clear the SDK Manager repository manifest cache.
  -h --help       : Help on a specific command.

                 Action "create avd":
  Creates a new Android Virtual Device.
  Options:
  -t --target  : Target ID of the new AVD. [required]
  -a --snapshot: Place a snapshots file in the AVD, to enable persistence.
  -c --sdcard  : Path to a shared SD card image, or size of a new sdcard for
             the new AVD.
  -p --path    : Directory where the new AVD will be created.
  -b --abi     : The ABI to use for the AVD. The default is to auto-select the
             ABI if the platform has only one ABI for its system images.
  -d --device  : The optional device definition to use. Can be a device index
             or id.
  -n --name    : Name of the new AVD. [required]
  -s --skin    : Skin for the new AVD.
  -g --tag     : The sys-img tag to use for the AVD. The default is to
             auto-select if the platform has only one tag for its system
             images.
  -f --force   : Forces creation (overwrites an existing AVD)
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552218/android-create-avd-size-on-windows-command-prompt)

```
android create avd -n Ev o4G -t 9 -c 8000M -s 480-800
```

Comment: I am not asking about name, target, skin. but other options

Answer (score 0):

just use **`echo no | android create avd -n name -t 9`**

Comment: In regard to your answer, the OP should first run "android list targets" and select the relevant target, he may not have target number 9.