# SDK Emulator - how to create without IDE

Tags: android, emulation

I can't find a solution for my problem anywhere else so I suppose there is no such a solution that I need. Still I rather want to ask for it.

Is there any option for create and set SDK Emulator without Android Studio or another tool?

If I want to use this emulator do I have to always create it somewhere else?

The main part of this is to set resolution of screen and the version of system.

Comment: Hi Jacob, you do not need AS, but you do need Android SDK as Virtual Device Manager is part of it. Alternatively, you could take a look at Genymotion (https://www.genymotion.com/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to create android emulator in command line with options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12846469/how-to-create-android-emulator-in-command-line-with-options)

Comment: Thanks guys, but I need to use SDK emulator. We use it in work.

Comment: @JakubJ. AVD (as used in that duplicate link) is the SDK emulator, Android Studio is just a fancy wrapper for it.

Comment: Yeah I know, I just want to create and set up the avd without AS and everything I have tried from command line is deprecated and can´t be used. :/